# Electron autoupdater: Mac update gets downloaded but gives error at install - "The command is disabled and cannot be executed"

Tags: macos, auto-update, electron-builder

We are facing an issue with Electron autoupdater on Mac where the update gets downloaded and we get a prompt to restart the app. However, when we press restart, this behavior continues in a loop and the logs show an error "The command is disabled and cannot be executed" at MacUpdater.js (Line: this.nativeUpdater.checkForUpdates()). Here's the code we are using:-

```
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  log.info('updated-download event'+releaseName+releaseNotes)
  const dialogOpts = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
    title: 'Application Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail:
      'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.',
  }

  dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
    if (returnValue.response === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
        app.exit();
      }, 6000);
    }
  });
})
```

Error Logs:-

```
[2023-04-27 23:14:33.708] [info]  Checking for update
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.833] [info]  Found version 1.0.1 (url: /download/flavor/default/1.0.1/osx_arm64/<App>-1.0.1-arm64-mac.zip)
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.834] [info]  update available [object Object]
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.834] [info]  Downloading update from /download/flavor/default/1.0.1/osx_arm64/<App>-1.0.1-arm64-mac.zip
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.840] [info]  Checked for macOS Rosetta environment (isRosetta=false)
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.843] [info]  Checked 'uname -a': arm64=true
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.944] [info]  Update has already been downloaded to /Users/$user/Library/Application Support/Caches/<App>-updater/pending/<App>-1.0.1-arm64-mac.zip).
[2023-04-27 23:14:34.948] [info]  updated-download
[2023-04-27 23:14:36.993] [warn]  Error: The command is disabled and cannot be executed
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Applications/<App>/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/out/MacUpdater.js:180:40)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1774:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
[2023-04-27 23:14:36.995] [error] Error: Error: The command is disabled and cannot be executed
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Applications/Zaperon.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/out/MacUpdater.js:180:40)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1774:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

Anyone else run into this issue?

We also tried using autoUpdater.nativeUpdater.quitAndInstall() as per few other threads on SW but no luck.